# discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: user is a required argument that is missing

Tags: python, discord

I've only seen no solutions for this, but im trying to check if the role of the user that sent the message is a DJ, if so then skip = True however i keep getting this error message

```
    async def skip(self, ctx, user: discord.Member):
        role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'DJ', ctx.message.guild.roles)

        if role in user.roles:
            skip = True
```

Comment: The problem is in how you are invoking the command

Comment: could you elaborate on what you mean? @FLAK-ZOSO

Comment: In Discord you wrote something like !skip @User or just !skip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the user that invoked the command use `ctx.author`:

```
    async def skip(self, ctx):
        role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'DJ', ctx.message.guild.roles)

        if role in ctx.author.roles:
            skip = True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async def skip(self, ctx, user: discord.Member):
```

This function (with the `Bot.command` decorator on it) asks the user for `1` positional argument: `user`.

---

When you invoke it from `Discord`, you have to write

```
!skip @User#0000
```

rather than

```
!skip
```

Since the command **requires** one **compulsory** positional argument.

---

Since you are using `user` as the `author` of the message, you can remove it from the arguments and just replace it this way:

```
async def skip(self, ctx, user: discord.Member=False):
    if (not user):
        user = ctx.author
    # Here you can use user as you did before
```